# How to validate this ł character in value

Tags: php, regex

I have following regex for validating currency with allowed symbols.

```
preg_match("/(?=.)^([\£|\€|\$|zł])?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/u","zł250")
```

It works fine for
250
$250
£112
112
€434
454

But its validating zł250.

Need to test **zł**

Comment: `But its validating zł250` This is unclear as to what you're asking. As it is now, your regex matches `zł250`. So, what's really your concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `([\£|\€|\$|zł])?` with `([£€$]|zł)?`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6coCQ/1)

The `[\£|\€|\$|zł]` construct is a character class matching 1 single character, either a `£`, `|`, `€`, `$`, `z` or `ł`. Thus, to make the `zł` match as a *sequence* of 2 chars, you need to take them out of the character class and use the `|` alternation operator on the grouping `(...)` construct level.